# Change visibility of a add-on (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gsuite-addons

Currently, I have an add-on (Google Apps Script) for Sheets, that was created as My Domain(on the g-suite group). However, I want to change to public now. I already look on the G Suite Marketplace Suite SDK but it doesn't have any possibility. After check here and the documentation, I found out that it's impossible to change it after the creation. However, my question is it's possible to delete this add-on and create a new one as public?

What would be another possibility?

Thank you for the help

Comment: So just for clarification. You have created a G Suite addon only for your domain and now want to publish for public use?  Is it mandatory to delete the one you have created right now? Or can you just change it?

Comment: Well you could publish it, although you will need to pass the app review and pen tests at some point if you use sensitive scopes.

Comment: Hi,  after some deep research I found out it's impossible to change the status from My Domain to Public